# SQL ERROR System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow]

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I would like my code to return a value but it returns me:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow]

I can't solve and make a right output process.

```
public static string Test()
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
        var vartest = cnn.Query("select grado from utenti where id='10'");
        //var result = output.ToDictionary(row => (string)row.Grado, row => (string)row.Nome ) ; (commento)
        //Console.WriteLine(vartest);

        cnn.Close();
        return vartest.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's the output of `vartest.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query` and `Query<T>` return multiple rows; `Query` is for `dynamic` rows; `Query<T>` is for typed rows. There are `QueryFirst[<T>]` and `QuerySingle[<T>]` for single rows.

If you're after a single value of a known type, then perhaps:

```cs
var vartest = cnn.QuerySingle<string>("select grado from utenti where id='10'");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you mean your return vartest.ToString(); is returning you the string "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow]" it is because your vartest is a list of items, you need to .ToString the item in the list

```
public static string ManagerFindid() 
{ 
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString())) 
    { 
        var select = cnn.Query("select id from utenti"); 
        if (select.Any()) 
        { 
            return select[0].ToString();
            // or do something with all the items in your list               
            foreach(string value in select)
            {
                 //add value into list view
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            //this is hit when there are no items returned from the select query 
            return "Nothing Returned from Query";
        } 
}
```

you could also handle there being multiple items returned from your SQL

```
foreach(string value in select)
{
    //do something with current value
}
```

Comment: so if i wanted to add more data in a listview, how should i proceed?
<blink>
public static string ManagerFindid()
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                var select = cnn.Query("select id from utenti");

                if (select.Any())
                { return select[0].ToString(); }
                else return select.ToString();
            }
        }
</blink>

Comment: you dont ever want to be returning the 'select.ToString();' rather you should return that there was nothing in the returned list. else 
  {
   return "Nothing Returned from Query"
  }

Comment: The Query " select id from utenti" will return all the Id values in you utenti table so if you want to add this data to a list view you should iterate through the list of strings returned from the select statement and add each one to the listview

Comment: i have updated my answer to show the code in more detail

Comment: With this I have two problems that I can't understand.
The first is because the string cannot be a dynamic value and it gives me this error: _Error CS0029 It is not possible to implicitly convert the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <dynamic>' to 'string'_

Comment: I tried to modify the code in this way to try to make the string a dynamic value, but I don't know what output it generates. (_dynamic select = cnn.Query("select id from utenti");_)

the second problem is to call the class, that is this class is in the **LoadUsers.cs** file, but I need to _foreach_ in the _listview1_ which is located in **Form1.cs**

Comment: [have make question just for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286897/c-sharp-how-to-use-listview-and-sqlite-database)