# C# - How to use ListView and SQLite database

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to add some data from a SQLite database, inside a ListView.
I'm having some difficulties as I want to insert all the data of the column and not a single record.

TEST CODE:

**Form1.cs {Load}**

```
private void home_form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Refresh();

            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.Columns.Add("ID");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Grado");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Cognome");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Nome");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Status");
        }
```

---

**Form1.cs {menu_button_gestionepax}**

```
private void menu_button_gestionepax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menu_button_dashboard.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
            panel_dashboard.Visible = false;
            gestionepersonale_panel.Visible = true;
            menu_button_gestionepax.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            listView1.Refresh();
            ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
            lst.SubItems.Add(LoadUsers.ManagerFind());
            lst.SubItems.Add(LoadUsers.ManagerFind());
            lst.SubItems.Add(LoadUsers.ManagerFind());
            lst.SubItems.Add(LoadUsers.ManagerFind());
            lst.SubItems.Add(LoadUsers.ManagerFind());

            listView1.Items.Add(lst);

            /*
            string[] row = { LoadUsers.ManagerFindid(), LoadUsers.ManagerFindid() };
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
            infobox_listview.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            */
        }
```

**LoadUsers.cs**

```
public dynamic string ManagerFind()
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
        var select = cnn.Query($"select id from utenti");

        if (select.Any())
        { return select[0].ToString(); }
        else return "wrong";
    }
}
```

I have also done various other tests and one of the difficulties in some cases is to call **string ManagerFind()** from **LoadUsers.cs**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get your rows and columns from your sql i know this is how you do it in SQL im sure there is a similar way to do it with sqlLite

```
         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionStringFromUserImput))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand =
                            new SqlCommand(
                                "select id from utenti",
                                connection)
                            {
                                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                                CommandTimeout = 20
                            };
                        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                DateTime datetimefield = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(0);
                                string stringField = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(1);
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: I converted the code and I did various tests but I can't insert the values ​​in multiple rows of the listview